# How to define the database schema name in EF CTP 5

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

I am using CTP 5 with existing database. Tables are created under a schema different than dbo. The SQL generated by the DbContext is using dbo. How do I make the DbContext use the correct schema name?

Comment: Using CTP5, tables are created under dbo for me.  Can you post you DBContext class?

Answer (score 1):

ToTable has an overload which accepts two strings: the first is the name of the table and the second the name of the schema.
The same possibility is offered by the attribute used to decorate the class.